# 404 Error when requesting .application manifest

Tags: .net, iis-6, clickonce

I recently published a new .NET ClickOnce application to our test server, but am unable to actually launch the application.

The auto-generated publish.htm file is served, as is any other file I place in the directory.
I can turn on Directory Browsing in IIS (6.0) and verify that the .application file is shown.
However, if I request the .application file, either through the publish.htm file or directly, I get a 404 error.

I've confirmed that the MIME types are already defined, and when I look at the request in the IIS logs I see that the error code is 404.0 with a win32 code of 2.  This would seem to indicate that the file isn't served because Windows can't locate it, but again, every other file in the directory is served without issue.

I've verified that the .application file has the exact same permissions as every other file on the site, and I can run the .application file manually from the server and watch the application install, so it seems Windows knows where the file is after all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out.  It actually wasn't IIS, or at least not directly.  MIME types were configured correctly for IIS to identify the files and allow download.

As this article explains (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380) had MIME types been preventing the download the logs should have shown 404.3 not 404.0.

Turns out that URLScan was also installed on the server and had been configured to disallow all requests that had a file extension not explicitly marked as allowed.  I don't really know the order of execution during such a request, but it looks like IIS interprets this as the file simply not existing on the drive rather than a permission/security issue.